How to display image from mysql on Angular frontend?
I implemented the option of selecting an image on the Angular frontend. The selected image is stored via the quarkus backend in the uploads folder on the backend, and the url of the image is stored in the mysql database. Now I want to retrieve the images via url from the database and display them on the frontend. The images are retrieved but do not want to be loaded because the route is not good. My database looks like this:
https://ibb.co/LSwBgSB
My frontend code:
service.ts
export class GalleryService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8085';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  uploadImage(file: File): Observable<Image> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('fileName', file.name);

    return this.http.post<Image>(`${this.apiUrl}/gallery`, formData);
  }

  getImages(): Observable<Image[]> {
    return this.http.get<Image[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/gallery`);
  }
}

component.ts
loadImages(): void {
    this.galleryService.getImages().subscribe((data: Image[]) => {
      this.images = data;
    });
  }

component.html
<div class="image" *ngFor="let image of images">
      <img [src]="image.url" alt="Image" />
    </div>
  </div>

Also the image of my results:
https://ibb.co/tbmZ6VJ

Is /uploads in your http://localhost:8085? if not, create an angular proxy to redirect to the server with the /uploads path or append the correct host where your images are stored.
